Can I use "multifold" to indicate that a figure has increased ... multifold without being specific?
A: increased fivefold from 2 to 10.
B: increased sevenfold from 3 to 21.

The figures for both A and B increased "multifold" that year.

As A and B didn't increase at the same rate, I find it hard to stress that they increased "several-fold" since I don't know what word to use.
Several times? Several-fold? Multifold? I don't think any of these "words" work.

Does this answer your question? Is "multiple times" the best word for this kind of situation? "Manyfold" is better. "Increased multifold" is sometimes used, e.g. in this paper by Swedish medical researchers, but it sounds a bit odd and mostly from non-native speakers. "More than doubled" is another alternative.

several-fold is the idiomatic choice for expressing the increase in a "ballpark"  (roughly estimated) manner.

How about "(significantly/greatly/notably) increased [many times over] that year"
